# ZTE AC2738 reliance netconnect is not able to connect

Tags: wvdial, lsusb

My ZTE reliance netconnect modem is not working.I've tried each possibility which is given on different forums,bt still unable to connect it.I've tried lsusb command,it shows my modem in list,also sometimes it get connected but when i restart my laptop agin same problem occurs.I've tried connecting my brothers netconnect,it is been detected in network manager as well as wvdial.but my modem is not working

Answer (score 0):

I could connect.... No issues.

Just follow the complete guideline on http://practicalubuntu.blogspot.com/2013/11/relience-netconnect-usb-modem-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.